# How to check Location Manager is running or not in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am creating location based application, I am implementing Delegate method of `CLLocationManager`,

I know there are two methods to start and stop location methods are:

```
[locationManger startUpdatingLocation];
[locationManger stopUpdatingLocation];
```

but i want to check is location manager is already running? is there any method for that like,

**isLocationManagerRunning**

if locationmanager is not running i have to start it.

I don't want to put **BOOL** in delegate method for checking it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to check if it is running or not, if you are not sure then just call `startUpdatingLocation` on your location manager.

If it is not running it will start, if it is running, it doesn't incur an overhead to start it again. As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startUpdatingLocation) says:

> Calling this method several times in succession does not automatically result in new events being generated. Calling stopUpdatingLocation in between, however, does cause a new initial event to be sent the next time you call this method.

Comment: Oh Thanks Abizerm, Thanks for Documentation.now i have no worry about  staring location manager

Comment: What if I want to give user the option to stop location manager, if it's running. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: @osrl I can't tell you the best way to give your user the option to turn of location services in the app - that's really dependent on your app and the design.

Comment: Of course it is. But I wanted to learn that if there is a way to know if location manager is running. Your answer states that there isn't. Maybe another way, like writing the state to UserDefaults may help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @osrl See if there is anything on this documentation page that may help you https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/determining_the_availability_of_location_services